# Is Vampire Knight still being written?

Tags: vampire-knight

I bought 17 volumes of the manga from Madman in Australia, and only recently did I get an email from them advertising an 18th volume.

I thought *Vampire Knight* had ended, but if volumes are still being released in Japan, then it'll take some time before they are translated and reprinted so it's ongoing. However, if it's finished in Japan then new English volumes are just catching up to the end, either way the translation is slow (I bought the 17 volumes back in March this year during a sale).

So I'm wondering: Is *Vampire Knight* still being written or has it finished in Japan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the manga has finished on May 24, 2013. However, there are 19 volumes total (93 chapters), so the English volumes are just slowly being translated, and you'll have to wait to get them all.