# How well did Vampire Knight sell?

Tags: vampire-knight

I'm trying to get an all-around view of how popular the show/manga of *Vampire Knight* was.

A rather straightforward question, but how well did both the anime and manga sell?  Were they both popular? What was the account of units sold for the anime each season?

Comment: Don't forget there are other books like the [*Fleeting Dreams* Novel](http://www.viz.com/books/print/vampire-knight-fleeting-dreams/11407?newsletter=preorder_img&utm_source=EmailDirect.com&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=20141120+VIZ+Print+Manga+-+Resident+Evil%2c+Vol.+1). also are you interested in the stats for japan or outside japan

Comment: For the anime, both sales in and out of Japan. That easy I can see if it was more of an international success its a success in Japan.

Comment: I don't think you'll truly grasp the popularity just from the anime, it stops short before the timeskip of the manga which is roughly half the story and the fight against Rido plays out differently (Zero and Yuki confront one another while Zero's still has those vines all over him)

Comment: Another reason that I want to know the sales (mainly of the anime because I have been reading that the manga was very popular) is because I want to know if part of the reason no season 3 was made was do to put sales or just not a GIGANTIC amount of sales.

Comment: Considering Guilty finished airing in 2008 with the final dvd volume release in 2009 while the final volume of the manga only came out [last year](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/5548/1587) i think the main reason would be to prevent the anime catching up to the manga and either going hiatus till 2013 or diverge from the manga. ofcause that's not confriming if a season 3 would ever be made, it took quite a while before Rozen Maiden was remade to follow the manga